# How can I limit the clickable area only for text in menu?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to php, css, html...learned from youtube videos.
I realised that if I move the mouse in between the menus, it still clickable and will direct to that page.
I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work at all.
Please help me out of this headache, appreicate!

Hi guys, I'm new to php, css, html...learned from youtube videos.
I realised that if I move the mouse in between the menus, it still clickable and will direct to that page.
I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work at all.
Please help me out of this headache, appreicate!
Hi guys, I'm new to php, css, html...learned from youtube videos.
I realised that if I move the mouse in between the menus, it still clickable and will direct to that page.
I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work at all.
Please help me out of this headache, appreicate!
Hi guys, I'm new to php, css, html...learned from youtube videos.
I realised that if I move the mouse in between the menus, it still clickable and will direct to that page.
I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work at all.
Please help me out of this headache, appreicate!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcB96.png)

CSS:

```
header{

background: rgb(61, 59, 59);
width:100%;
height:50px;
}

.widget {

list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;


}


.page-wrap {
   

 padding:2rem 0;


}


header .top-bar {

list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:flex; 

}

header .container {

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:100%;

}

header .top-bar li a {

font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size:15px;
padding:0.25rem 2rem;
color:rgb(218, 208, 208);

}

header .top-bar li {
   

position:relative;
left:0px;

}

header .top-bar li:first-child a {
padding-left:0;
}

header .top-bar li:last-child a {
padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>


    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
    
<header>

    <div class="container">
        <?php
                wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 
                        'menu_class' => 'top-bar'
                    )
            );
        ?>
    </div>

</header>

Comment: If you get a notice saying that the text to code ratio in your question is too low, then that does _not_ mean, “please copy&paste the same text into it multiple times.”

Comment: lol yeah I'm new in here, so didn't know until paste a lot content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add margin in `li` to get space between two menu link and remove padding left and right from `a` tag

```
header .top-bar li {
   position:relative;
   left:0px;
   margin-left: 30px;
}
header .top-bar li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

header .top-bar li a {
   font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight:normal;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size:15px;
   padding:0.25rem 0;
   color:rgb(218, 208, 208);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Minal! It works! One more questions, "remove padding left and right from a tag" means remove "padding" from "header .top-bar li a" right? After I tried your correction, the space between menus are tight now, how can I increase the space without changing clickable text area?  Thanks Again !!!!

Comment: One more questions, "remove padding left and right from a tag" means remove "padding" from "header .top-bar li a" right? After I tried your correction, the space between menus are tight now, how can I increase the space without changing clickable text area? Thanks Again !!!!

Comment: yes remove padding from `header .top-bar li a` and add margin-left in `header .top-bar li` to get space between to menu